# cloudsearch query to boost exact match on range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

In a cloudsearch **structured** query.

I have a couple of fields I am searching on.

On field one, the user selects "2"
On field two the user selects "1"

I am wanting to run this as a range query, so that the results that are returned are -1 to +1

eg. on field one the range would be 1,3 and on field 2 it would be 0,2

What I am wanting to do is sort the results so that the results that match both field 1 and field 2 are at the top, and the rest under it.

eg. where field one=2 and field two =1 would be at the top and the rest are not in any specific order,

note: I do need to end up sorting the results by distance, so that all the exact matching results are in distance order, then all the rest are ordered by distance.

I am sure I can do this with 2 queries, just trying to make it work in one query if at all possible to lighten the load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your fields are 'a' and 'b', and the specified values are `a=2` and `b=1` (as in your example, except I've named the fields 'a' and 'b' instead of 'one' and 'two'). Here are the various terms of your query.

**Range Query**

This is the query for the range a±1 and b±1 where `a=2` and `b=1`:

```
q=(and (range field=a[1,3]) (range field=b[0,2]))
```

**Rank Expression**

For your rank expression, compute a distance-based score using absolute value so that scores 'a' and 'b' can't cancel each other out (like `a=3,b=0` would, for example):

```
expr.rank1=abs(a-2)+abs(b-1)
```

**Sort by Rank**

That defined a ranking expression named `rank1`, which we now want to sort by, starting with the lowest values ('0' means a=2,b=1):

```
sort=rank1 asc
```

**Return the Rank**

For debugging purposes, you may want return the ranking score:

```
return=rank1
```

Put all those terms together and you've got your query.

**Further Potentially-Useful Things**

If you want to get fancy and penalize things in a non-linear way, you can use `exp`. For example, if you want to differentiate between 'a' and 'b' both being off by 1 vs 'a' being an exact match and 'b' being off by 2 (eg `a=3,b=2` will rank ahead of `a=2,b=3` even though the previous ranker would give them both a score of 2):

```
expr.rank1=exp(abs(a-2))+exp(abs(b-1))
```

And you can use boolean logic and the ternary operator to detect and prefer certain results that meet certain criteria, eg to give a big boost when 'a' and 'b' are on-target, a smaller boost when 'a' *or* 'b' is on target, etc (since we're sorting in low-to-high, a boost in rank is actually achieved by adding less to the result):

```
((a==1&&b==2)?0:100)+((a==1||b==2)?0:1000)+abs(a-1)+abs(b-2)
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-expressions.html